# can not find symbol method Iterator()

Tags: java, collections

Hello everyone i have started learning collection in java and trying to write a simple program but i am getting 2 errors please have a look and help me out.

```
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.*;
    class ArrayListDemo1{
    public static void main(String... s){
    ArrayList<Integer> al = new ArrayList<Integer>();
 // ArrayList al = new ArrayList();
    int x[] = {1, -1, 2, -2, 3, -3, 4, -4};
    for(int i=0; i<x.length;i++){
        al.add(x[i]);
    }
    System.out.println(al);
//  Iterator<Integer> i = al.Iterator();
    Iterator i = al.Iterator();
    while(i.hasNext()){
        Integer z = (Integer)i.next();
//      Integer z = i.next();
        if(z.intValue < 0)  
        i.remove(); 
    }   
    System.out.println(al);
}
}
```

Comment: where are the errors??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
 1. Iterator i = al.iterator();//here method is case sensitive
 2. intValue() not intValue, is a method.
```

Comment: you missed the second one.

Answer (score 3):

Java is case sensitive and methods usually start in a lower case letter. It should be `al.iterator();`

Beside that, `intValue` is a method, so `z.intValue` should be `z.intValue()`.

Comment: you missed the second one.

Answer (score 2):

**1st Error**

Methods usually follows camelcase and are case-sensitive.

It should be `al.iterator()`

Please have a look [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#iterator%28%29)

**2nd Error**

`intValue()` is a function, please refer [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#intValue%28%29).

change `if(z.intValue < 0)`   to `if(z.intValue() < 0)`

**After Run, output**

```
[1, -1, 2, -2, 3, -3, 4, -4]
[1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Tested [here](https://ideone.com/Q3ZfKe)

Answer (score 0):

And you write **intValue**.it is false.it should be **intValue().**

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 compile errors:

```
Iterator i = al.Iterator();
```

in java method names start with a lowercase character, also Iterator is a raw type, you should give it a generic type:

```
Iterator<Integer> i = al.iterator();
```

your second problem is here:

```
z.intValue
```

Integer doesn't have a public field intValue, but a method intValue() that returns the desired value:

```
z.intValue()
```

As a hint: I don't know why you use the Iterator here, but you could also use a for-each loop for the task of removing a list item:

```
for ( Integer integer : al )
{
    if ( integer.intValue() < 0 )
        al.remove( integer );
}
```